# How to load devnp-ncm.so in qnx OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am running QNX OS (`650SP1`) in `VMplayer`. I would like to load `devnp-ncm.so` driver.

I have tried following things -

1) # `io-pkt-v4-hc -d /lib/dll/devnp-ncm.so path=/dev/io-usb/io-usb -ptcpip verbose &`

2) # `io-pkt-v4-hc &`
   # `mount -T io-pkt devnp-ncm.so`

Please give me some suggestion how to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following command and it worked -

`# io-pkt-v4-hc -d ncm pnp verbose &`

or you can specify path i.e. `#io-pkt-v4-hc -d ncm pnp path=/lib/dll/devnp-ncm.so verbose &`

But make sure the sequence. It matters.
If you give "pnp" after "path" then it will not work.